# Fetch Labels from Blogger Api JSON using Retrofit and Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I want to fetch the **labels** from the Blogger api JSON. Here is my json

```
{
 "kind": "blogger#postList",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "blogger#post",
   "id": "12222222225",
   "blog": {
    "id": "3333333333"
   },
   "published": "2018-09-28T02:38:00-07:00",
   "updated": "2018-09-29T00:05:24-07:00",
   "etag": "some tag",
   "url": "some url",
   "selfLink": "some link",
   "title": "Test post 2",
   "content": "post content",
   "author": {
    "id": "a11111111111",
    "displayName": "Some Name",
    "url": "Author url",
    "image": {
     "url": "Author image"
    }
   },
   "replies": {
    "totalItems": "0",
    "selfLink": "Comment url"
   },
   "labels": [
    "label1",
    "label 2"
   ]
  },

  {
   "kind": "blogger#post",
   "id": "12222222225",
   "blog": {
    "id": "3333333333"
   },
   "published": "2018-09-28T02:38:00-07:00",
   "updated": "2018-09-29T00:05:24-07:00",
   "etag": "some tag",
   "url": "some url",
   "selfLink": "some link",
   "title": "Test post 2",
   "content": "post content",
   "author": {
    "id": "a11111111111",
    "displayName": "Some Name",
    "url": "Author url",
    "image": {
     "url": "Author image"
    }
   },
   "replies": {
    "totalItems": "0",
    "selfLink": "Comment url"
   },
   "labels": [
    "label1"
   ]
  },

  {
   "kind": "blogger#post",
   "id": "12222222225",
   "blog": {
    "id": "3333333333"
   },
   "published": "2018-09-28T02:38:00-07:00",
   "updated": "2018-09-29T00:05:24-07:00",
   "etag": "some tag",
   "url": "some url",
   "selfLink": "some link",
   "title": "Test post 2",
   "content": "post content",
   "author": {
    "id": "a11111111111",
    "displayName": "Some Name",
    "url": "Author url",
    "image": {
     "url": "Author image"
    }
   },
   "replies": {
    "totalItems": "0",
    "selfLink": "Comment url"
   }
  }

 ],
 "etag": "some etag"
}
```

And here is my BlogPost object -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BlogPost {
    private String kind;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public BlogPost(String kind, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.kind = kind;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}

class Item {

    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String url;
    private String published;


    public Item(String title, String content, String url, String published) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.url = url;
        this.published = published;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getPublished() {
        return published;
    }
}
```

And here is my getData method where I pass the data to recyclerview

```
private void getData(){
        Call<BlogPost> blogPost = BloggerApi.getService().getPostList();
        blogPost.enqueue(new Callback<BlogPost>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BlogPost> call, Response<BlogPost> response) {
                BlogPost list = response.body();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new PostAdaptar(MainActivity.this,list.getItems()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BlogPost> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Everything is working fine. I can fetch total three posts and display it into recyclerview. But I want to get the **labels** and show into the recyclerview post item.

But my question is how to get the labels? Do I need to create a separate class called **Labels** and pass it to **Item** class? If anyone has any example please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: please check this tutorial http://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/09/how-to-convert-any-blogger-blog-into.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could either create a `Labels` class for it, I recommend [this website](http://jsonschema2pojo.org) to automatically convert your Json into Java object classes for you.

Another approach could be making your `Item` a JSONObject and do something like this

```
JSONObject jObj = list.getItems().get(0);
ArrayList<String> labels = jObj.getStringArray("labels");
```